# What package does the menus in Unity belong to?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, menu, scaling

I am experiencing a bug in Unity and I want to report it via Launchpad, but I realized I don't know which package is the responsible for it. How can I know that?

What is happening is that the menu on the upper right corner of the desktop doesn't show complete. It is partially hidden as you can see in the image. This only happens when scaling the screen x2. (You can see the image). How can I know which is the package not working correctly?

[This is what I am seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGkr7.jpg)

Comment: My guess is the graphics driver.

Comment: My GPU is the one inside the Core i7 6500U. Something quite standard. Intel's propietary driver was detected automatically when I installed Ubuntu. What could be going wrong?

Comment: The issue is that many manufacturers produce their own (proprietary) drivers, for windows/mac, but scarcely support linux. Futhermore, they don't share a lot of information to the open source community.